# Searchable Phonebook on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Is there any feature in SharePoint where we can add a searchable Phonebook?
It could be a handy option for users.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also create a document that contains all the contact info, maybe an Excel spreadsheet would work best? Search will index that and then you could make a trimmed search that would only return results from that document. Tag the search bar "Company Directory" and that'd be that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a contact list and add names and phones, and with the magic of JSLink you can change the look of it to suit your UI needs

Answer (score 0):

You could list everyone in a standard SharePoint List and make the searchbox do filtering on every keystroke with some code in a Calculated Column

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/#/Create/SearchFilter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've done it before with some js script. if you interested, you can read the article from here: https://hasankoroglu.com/2017/05/26/sharepoint-rest-api-ile-telefon-rehberi/ but the article is Turkish. if you want i try to explain it from here.